# Why are most of the commands missing?

Tags: 8, console

Most of console commands are missing from the output of `drupal list`.

I am using Drupal Console version 0.11.3, which outputs the following error message.

> [WARNING] In order to list all of the available commands you should install Drupal first.

The multi-site is correctly configured.

I have created an empty /sites/default/settings.php and it is still not working, i.e. it still not showing most of the Drupal console commands.

Why do I get that error message?

Answer (score 3):

Specifying the root resolved this for me. Having used composer to install drupal through drupal-composer/drupal-project the site is put in a "web" folder so the following worked.

```
drupal --root=/var/www/html/web list
```

I had also run the init command beforehand

```
drupal --root=/var/www/html/web init
```